# How to check for empty cells in csv before converting to int (Python script)?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am new to stackoverflow and python so please forgive me if this question lacks detail

I want to import data from a csv file to a table in *Postgres*. However, I'm not sure how to check for null values. I would like to import certain values as ints (these values for some reason have a .0 trailing them ie 10.0 when I want 10) . Some of the cells for on_hand and on_order are `null` though - how would I go about checking to see if these cells are `null` and if they are `null`, to simply do a `row[2].strip` and `row[3].strip`?

```
for row in reader:
    arg = {
        'name': row[0].strip(),
        'description': row[1].strip(),
        'on_hand': int(float(row[2].strip())),
        'on_order': int(float(row[3].strip()))
    }
    cur.execute(
        """INSERT INTO 
        "Inventory"("Name","Description","On hand","On order")
         select %(name)s, 
            %(description)s, 
            %(on_hand)s,
            %(on_order)s,
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM "Inventory" WHERE "Name"=%(name)s
            );""", arg)
```

thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Don't forget to accept an answer if your query was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this - basically convert to float only if `row[2]` actually has some value, else just return an empty string `""` (You may return `None` as well)/

```
for row in reader:
    arg = {
        'name': row[0].strip(),
        'description': row[1].strip(),
        'on_hand': int(float(row[2].strip())) if row[2].strip() else "",
        'on_order': int(float(row[3].strip())) if row[3].strip() else ""
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `int(float)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham umm sorry, blind copy paste, corrected now.

Comment: You had me scratching my head for a minute ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was wrong earlier, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088097/how-to-check-for-empty-cells-in-csv-before-converting-to-int-python-script/25088485?noredirect=1#comment39037408_25088485)

Comment: Ah ok, I just realized they were stored as floats

Answer (score 0):

I would just `try` to cast and in case of a `ValueError` exception assign `None` to to the variable.

```
for row in reader:

    try:
        on_hand = int(float(row[2]))
    except ValueError:
        on_hand = None

    try:
        on_order = int(float(row[3]))
    except ValueError:
        on_order = None

    arg = {
        'name': row[0].strip(),
        'description': row[1].strip(),
        'on_hand': on_hand,
        'on_order': on_order
    }
```

Comment: You will need to move `on_order` also within the try block.

Comment: @mu無 Sure. Just an example.

Comment: And you are also blindly copy pasting `int(float(variable))`, which I too had earlier done in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088097/how-to-check-for-empty-cells-in-csv-before-converting-to-int-python-script/25088155#comment39037166_25088155) :P

Comment: @mu無 That is necessary in case of a "doted" number like `10.0`